# laravel - Custom class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create my custom repository classes so I have created repository class which extends abstract class (with base, model methods):
**BoardCategoryRepository**

```
namespace App\Repositories\Board;

use App\Repositories\Repository;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BoardCategoryRepository extends Repository
{
    public function getAllCategoriesWithBoards(): Collection
    {
        return DB::table('board_category')
            ->join('board', 'board_category.id', '=', 'board.category_id')
            ->get()
        ;
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
namespace Community\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\Board\BoardCategoryRepository;
use Community\BoardCategory;
use function compact;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var BoardCategoryRepository
     */
    protected $boardCategoryRepository;

    public function __construct(BoardCategory $boardCategory)
    {
        $this->boardCategoryRepository = new BoardCategoryRepository($boardCategory);
    }
}
```

and `composer dump-autoload` but I getting error `Class 'App\Repositories\Board\BoardCategoryRepository' not found` - why?

Comment: Make Sure the route is correct

Comment: You haven't included filenames. Are you sure files has correct names (with valid letter case) and are in valid directories?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace for your Repository is `App\Repositories\Board` but your controller's namespace is `Community\Http\Controllers`. Should it in fact be `Community\Http\Controllers`.

Alternatively, check in your composer.json and look for the `PSR-4` section check to see App is registered there. For example;

```
 "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
 }
```